# Hvac Zone dampers

Tags: hvac

I have a 2 zone Honeywell damper problem. The actuators ar power on spring closed. When I ask for heat upstairs everything works fine. Then when I turn off upstairs and ask for head downstairs everything works fine as welll BUT if I ask for heat in both areas both dampers close. Any help please

Comment: What controller are you using?

Comment: Yes, what make and model is your zone board?

Comment: It’s a Honeywell HZ221

Comment: What make and model is your furnace, for that matter, and what lights are on on the zone board when both zones call for heat?

Comment: It’s a Honeywell HZ221 wired for damper closed but dampers are opening on power individually for upstairs and downstairs but both spring close when both t stats asking for heat

Comment: Goodman A24-05 air handler

Comment: @Rob -- we need to know what the lights on the zone board are saying during the dual zone call situation